# java.rmi.NotBoundException

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, rmi

i have written small RMI chat program and its compiling properly.but when i try to run Client program it results exception "`java.rmi.NotBoundException - ServerInterface`"
Server program runs without any errors..please help me to solve this.

here is some of  Client code

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
String address = "rmi://localhost/ServerInterface";
try
{
ServerInterface si= (ServerInterface) Naming.lookup(address);
new Thread(new Client(si)).start();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
System.err.println(e.toString()) ;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A NotBoundException is thrown if an attempt is made to lookup or unbind in the registry a name that has no associated binding.

What is your server code look like? This exception you are having most likely caused by server not set up properly.

I think in your server code you are bind with name `ChatServer`

```
 Naming.rebind("ChatServer", new Server());
```

But in your client code you are using `ServerInterface` name

```
String address = "rmi://localhost/ServerInterface";
```

For more details [Naming](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/rmi/Naming.html)

Comment: 'Mainly'? What other reason is there?

Comment: thnak you..i correct that to Naming.rebind("ServerInterface", new Server())..but still it produces the same error like before  ServerInterface is the interface which im implement Server program

Comment: @SumitSingh I read your answer. I am asking you a question about it. You haven't answered it. 'Mainly' implies that there are other causes. What other cause is there?

Comment: @SumitSingh Wrong again, nothing to do with me, and no misunderstanding either. Just a complete failure to answer my question.

Comment: @MukulGoel I could show you dozens. I saw one today with a tick and 20 upvotes that went to 19 for some unexplained reason.

Comment: @EJP , ahaan.. strange. .. Sir, I aint getting between you and Sumit. I just browsed to this post and without reading comments I made my comment. :) ;)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are attempting to look up a name that is not bound.

> public class NotBoundException extends Exception
>
> A NotBoundException
> is thrown if an attempt is made to lookup or unbind in the registry a
> name that has no associated binding.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your registry.rebind(ClassName.class.getSimpleName(), new ClassImplementaion()) is match to your ClassImplementation.